# Convert aggregate SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I decided to try my hand at LINQ and so far its been a miserable failure.  I need to convert the following SQL query to LINQ:

```sql
SELECT 
MAX(A.NEXTPAYMENTDATE) as NextPaymentDate
, SUM(B.PurchasePrice) - SUM(A.Amount) AS BALANCE
, c.FirstName
, c.LastName
, b.[year]
, b.make
, b.model
FROM Payments A
JOIN Vehicles B ON A.VehicleId = B.Id
JOIN Customers C ON  b.CustomerId = c.Id
GROUP BY VehicleId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, b.[year], b.make, b.model
HAVING SUM(B.PurchasePrice) - SUM(A.Amount) > 0
```

This is what I have so far.  It seems to work to a certain extent, but I don't know how to progress from here.

```cs
var groupedpayments = 
    from payments in db.Payments
    group payments by new { payments.VehicleId }
    into paymentGroup
        let maxDate = paymentGroup.Max(x => x.NextPaymentDate)
        let paid = paymentGroup.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    select 
    new { Payments = paymentGroup.Where(x => x.NextPaymentDate == maxDate)};
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your result set wrong? Incomplete?

Comment: gideon, I need to somehow get a balance by subtracting the vehicle purchaseprice from the sum(payment.amount).  Then from this I only want to see vehicles that have a balance > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you need.

```
var query =
    Payments.Join(Vehicles, p => p.VehicleId, v => v.Id, (p, v) => new {p, v})
        .Join(Customers, d => d.v.CustomerId, c => c.Id, (d, c) => new {d, c})
        .GroupBy(r => 
                   new {
                           r.d.p.VehicleId,
                           r.d.v.year,
                           r.d.v.make,
                           r.d.v.model,
                           r.c.FirstName,
                           r.c.LastName
                       },
                 (g, data) =>
                   new {
                           FirstName = g.FirstName,
                           LastName = g.LastName,
                           Year = g.year,
                           Make = g.make,
                           Model = g.model,
                           NextPaymentDate = data.Max(dd => dd.d.p.NEXTPAYMENTDATE),
                           Balance = data.Sum(dd => dd.d.v.PurchasePrice)
                                      - data.Sum(dd => dd.d.p.Amount)})
         .Where(r => r.Balance > 0);
```

Comment: Hamlet, I'm going to give you the points for taking your time to figure this problem out.  Unfortunately, this LINQ query is far to complex for me to figure out.  Looks like I'll be best off just writing a stored procedure and calling that.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out completely, but I just wanted to let you know that it is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Nothing complex, the same semantics, but different syntax. Good luck.